# Method to extract stat_xspline fit

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a plot with the geom_xspline smoother for a small number of points and I would like to get the smoothed y values for all the integer values in the range of X. Any idea how to get them?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalt)
avgTheta<-c(-0.36,0.497085315,0.599960557,0.574336142,0.400831445,0.105615915,-0.250223072)
ageGroup<-c(11,16,23,33,43,53,63)
df <- data.frame(ageGroup, avgTheta)
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = ageGroup, y = avgTheta))
p + 
 geom_xspline(spline_shape=-0.3, size=2, color='lightblue') +
 geom_point(size=3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xspline()` function from the `graphics` package will return the points.  You should be able to use the `draw=FALSE` argument, but I still needed to call `plot.new()` first before it would work.  First, make data.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalt)
avgTheta<-c(-0.36,0.497085315,0.599960557,0.574336142,0.400831445,0.105615915,-0.250223072)
ageGroup<-c(11,16,23,33,43,53,63)
df <- data.frame(ageGroup, avgTheta)
```

Second, use `xspline()` function and turn result into a data frame.

```
plot.new()
xs <- xspline(x=df$ageGroup, y=df$avgTheta, shape=-0.3, draw=FALSE)
xs <- do.call(data.frame, xs)
```

The values in `xs` are the values that would make the curve.  They are not just the integer values of `x` and it doesn't appear that there is a way to make them just the integer values.  Make ggplot to show that the two results do the same thing.

```
p2 <- ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data=xs, aes(x=x, y=y), size=2, color='lightblue') +
  geom_point(data=df, aes(x = ageGroup, y = avgTheta), size=3)
p2
```

[image]

---

**EDIT**

To address the other part of the question about getting the values at the integers, it doesn't seem possible to do this with `xspline()` alone.  However, once you've got the curve values, you could fit a model to the `x` and `y` values for the curve and from that you could predict the integer values.  For example, one reasonably simple model would be a loess curve.

```
lo <- loess(y ~ x, data=xs, span=.1)
cor(xs$y, fitted(lo))
# [1] 0.9999994
```

What you can see from the above is that the correlation of the fitted values from this model and the observed `y` values for the `xspline()` curve is approximately 1.  That is, the loess model nearly perfectly reproduces the curve.  Now, you could predict the loess curve values at the integers of x.

```
pred.dat <- data.frame(x=seq(min(df$ageGroup), max(df$ageGroup), by=1))
fit <- predict(lo, newdata=pred.dat)
pred.dat$fit <- fit
head(pred.dat)
#    x         fit
# 1 11 -0.35999980
# 2 12 -0.17044086
# 3 13  0.01636747
# 4 14  0.19932127
# 5 15  0.37068414
# 6 16  0.49624180
```

Comment: xspline now creates 295 observations - which sounds arbitrary to me.
Would be great if I could specify a number to make sure I have an observation for each integer value. As it is I can round it. Many thanks.

Comment: @SunWuKung I added a method for being able to get the integer values.  It is a sort of round about way, but it seems to work.